# how to display digits in a number printed, separated by two spaces? in python

Tags: python, printing, digits

Takes a number between 1 – 32767 from the user and passes the number to a function (print_value) as argument.  The function will display the digits in the number separated by two spaces. For example, if the user enters an integer, 3467; The function should print 3  4  6  7.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to convert the integer to a string and then use [.join()](https://pythonbasics.org/join/) to join the characters of a string together with specified characters in between.

```
def print_value(number):
    print('  '.join(str(number)))  # converts number to a string and inserts two spaces between each character ('  ')
```

This works because .join() is used to *join* together the elements of a list into a string. Strings can also be interpreted as a list of individual characters ('hi' = ['h', 'i']), so using .join() on them works as well.